# Reading powershell clixml in python

Tags: python, powershell

I have an XML file that was written from a powershell "Export-Clixml" call and it appears quite strange to me.

Here's a very simple sample:

```
PS C:\> Get-Date | Export-Clixml sample.xml
PS C:\> cat .\sample.xml
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <DT>2018-03-21T08:05:39.5085956-04:00</DT>
    <MS>
      <Obj N="DisplayHint" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="0">
          <T>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.DisplayHintType</T>
          <T>System.Enum</T>
          <T>System.ValueType</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>DateTime</ToString>
        <I32>2</I32>
      </Obj>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

How are you supposed to parse these "Objs" and "MS" and "TN" and the rest of it? I need something that can reliably read this in python. Does anyone have a way to do this?

ConvertTo-Xml has an output like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Collections.Hashtable">
    <Property Name="Key" Type="System.String">someKey</Property>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.String">value</Property>
    <Property Name="Key" Type="System.String">otherKey</Property>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.String">otherValue</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

So there's no way to tell which "key" goes with which "value" other than the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell's Extended Type System supports auxiliary properties and type information, and the XML serialization scheme thus needs some way of representing this metadata. In your case, everything under `MS` contains properties native to the **M**onad**S**hell (the original moniker for PowerShell). `TN` is likely short for **T**ype**N**ames.

The full [schema you're looking for is available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt766752.aspx) if you want to write a parser/deserializer in python

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.However it seems strange that powershell would generate something so foreign that not one other language community has written a parser for it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you regenerate the file?
If so use `ConvertTo-Xml` rather than `Export-CliXml`

```
$Xml = Get-Date | ConvertTo-Xml
$Xml.Save("C:\Temp\File.xml")
```

File content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.DateTime">21/03/2018 15:25:33</Object>
</Objects>
```

Convert hash table to object before export/save

```
$HashTable =
@{
    Prop1 = "Value1"
    Prop2 = "Value2"
    Prop3 = "Value2"
}

$Object = New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $HashTable


$Xml = $Object | ConvertTo-Xml
$Xml.Save("C:\Temp\File.xml")
```

Comment: That's actually worse in most cases. The actual data is in a System.Collections.Hashtable and so it gets serialized as a list of "Property" items with a "Name" of "Key" or "Value" but no actual association between the key and value other than their position. I put a sample in the question.

Comment: @MichaelB do you mean the data you are exporting to xml is in a hash table? Or am I misunderstanding? Can you post an example? My answer has a datetime object as per the question.

Comment: @MichaelB updated the answer to convert the hash table to an object before converting to xml.